# Set-up TypeScript Debugging in VSCode

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I spent last 24 hours watching/reading tutorials and posts on how to debug `TypeScript` in `VSCode`. But I have been failing every time.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Node TS",
            "preLaunchTask": "typescript",
            "program": "node ${workspaceFolder}\\src\\app.ts",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}\\dist\\**\\*.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**task.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "typescript",
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "start-no-watch",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run the debugger, it runs the server fine. but it never hits any break-points. When stops the server it errors out `prelaunch terminated with exit code 1` and clicking on `Show Errors` says `No problem have been detected`. What am I doing wrong beside banging my head on the wall?

**NOTE:** Please don't mark this as duplicate. I have tried the other posts, but I am having a feel that I am missing something small that I can't figure out.

Comment: This has been a hit and miss for me as well. Few things to try... use latest TS, update VS Code, use Chrome Debugger extension to debug server code in Chrome. I personally use a ton of logging and if I must debug, I debug the output JS code.

Comment: well that sucks!!! They advertise it as if its easy and sweet like a piece of cake. Logging is very frustrating and time consuming. Chrome Debugger is good if I am debugging the front-end. But how would I debug the back-end with it?

Comment: You can use CD for debugging nodejs code. V8 uses inspector protocol to allow attaching external debuggers including CD. It's not as convenient as integrated debugging, but worth a try. I have been able to carry on because mostly I prefer putting a ton of tracing, it helps debug prod issues quickly. But that's just me, YMMV.